# How to change the width of tabs in a QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, indentation, qplaintextedit

When using the QPlaintextEdit in PyQt5, if I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button on my keyboard I get a tab space which is equal to size of six spaces together. But I want it to be the size of four spaces, so that when I use:

```
TextEdit.setPlainTextEdit('\t')
```

I should get a indentation of a tab space, which is as long as four spaces altogether.

I tried using four spaces instead of a tab space, but things got complex, as code became more lengthy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The width of a tab can be set with [setTabStopDistance](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#tabStopDistance-prop). This takes a floating-point value, which can be calculated by using the [QFontMetricsF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html) class:

```
textedit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
textedit.setTabStopDistance(
    QtGui.QFontMetricsF(textedit.font()).horizontalAdvance(' ') * 4)
```

However, this method was only introduced in Qt-5.10, so for Qt4 and older versions of Qt5, you must use [setTabStopWidth](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit-obsolete.html) (which is now documented as obsolete):

```
textedit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
textedit.setTabStopWidth(textedit.fontMetrics().width(' ') * 4)
```

The big disadvantage of this method is that it only takes *integer* values. This means that it isn't guaranteed give accurate results with fonts that have non-integer character widths (e.g. the DejaVu fonts and many others).

Comment: These days `QFontMetrics::width()` is deprecated (since Qt-5.11 I believe). It's recommended to use `QFontMetricsF::horizontalAdvance()` instead from now on.